# Git: 'git log' command with -l option

Tags: git

I have read 'Git Hooks' topic in Atlassian's Git Tutorial before. The text I have quoted in this topic:

> Post-Commit
>
> The post-commit hook is called immediately after the commit-msg hook.
>   It can’t change the outcome of the git commit operation, so it’s used
>   primarily for notification purposes.
>
> The script takes no parameters and its exit status does not affect the
>   commit in any way. For most post-commit scripts, you’ll want access to
>   the commit that was just created. You can use git rev-parse HEAD to
>   get the new commit’s SHA1 hash, or you can use git log -l HEAD to get
>   all of its information.

Although I read -l option in git log man page, I don't understand git log command with -l option what it is. What is the git log with -l option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the context of that paragraph, I think it means to say `git log -1 HEAD`. That is, the digit 1, not the letter l. This will return information about the most recent commit as the docs say.

```
jack in ~/projects/some_project on master
$ git log -1 HEAD
commit f54d65611fd30633e806f8bce83a56cff841d98e
Merge: d45b51b 1619b26
Author: Jack Bracken <my.email@foo.bar>
Date:   Tue Oct 4 17:27:57 2016 +0100

    Merge branch 'cleanup' into 'master'

    Use pooled redis. Tidy code according to rubocop recommendations.

    See merge request !18
```

As far as I can tell `git log -l HEAD` does nothing meaningful. This is most likely a mistake in their docs.

Comment: I have sent an e-mail to Atlassian for this.